# Package biblatex Warning: No driver for entry type '@article'

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm using biblatex with backend biber. I implemented a bibliography like I always do using with entries using the entry type `@article`.

The problem I now have is, that I get the error message:

> Package biblatex Warning: No driver for entry type '@article'. Using fallback driver on input line 554

I don't know where I messed up and sadly the log doesn't show me any further information. Especially since the same bib setting worked with `@article` on other documents. I spell checked every entry labeled with @article.

Comment: The way this message is coded in the `biblatex` core means that it should never output the entry type with a leading `@`. If you really have `No driver for entry type '@article'.` that suggests some code is misusing a `biblatex` command. It's hard to say how that happens without seeing an example document that reproduces the warning. Please show us a short and compilable example document (along with an example `.bib` entry) that produces this warning. (See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)

Comment: Any news here? As mentioned above you really should not be getting this message, but it is close to impossible to identify the core of the issue without an example document that reproduces the problem. If there is no development here in due time I will vote to close this question.

Comment: I voted to close this question, because the problem cannot be reproduced with the information provided in the question so far. As I mentioned above, if the code is kosher, you should not get this message at all. Since we haven't seen any of your code, there is little we can do to tell you where things might be wrong.